# A source compiled with vs2008 produce a binary that is different from the same source compiled directly by csc at command line

Tags: visual-studio-2008, msbuild, csc

I can't understand why If I compile the **same** source with Visual Studio 2008 (MSBuild) and then with csc (or NANT) at command line I can't obtain exacly the same binary file (the same assembly).

The command line is the same that is invoked by visual studio because I copy the command from the output window and then paste the command to the vs2008 command prompt.

I know that if I compile the same source at different time I obtain different binary because of the timestamps in the assembly metadata. In fact, if I compare two binaries produced by vs2008 at different time I notice small difference between the binary data.

But if I compile with vs and then with csc the binaries are very very different!
Do you know why? What's wrong?

Comment: What is different about them?

Comment: What if you disassemble your assemblies using ildasm.exe (from the Visual Studio Command Prompt)? You can save the a dump and diff it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no guarantee of any particular order of metadata made by the compiler. That said, there's nothing intentionally causing a different ordering between the in-proc compiler and csc.exe.

Answer (score 0):

A very bold guess, but maybe the environment variables are not the same in the VS IDE and your terminal. In a worse case scenario maybe your terminal version links against another .NET framework or at least against a couple of other libraries/ code files or compiler switches?

Comment: @Scott: The timestamp issue explains why building two binaries at different times produces *slightly* different binaries - but not why the binaries built from the command-line are *very* different from the VS ones.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said whether you're building debug or binary builds in Visual Studio. I'm not sure that the command-line default is the same as *either* of them.

Try building with explicit `/debug` and `/o` switches (set to however you want them) and match them up in Visual Studio. Also define the DEBUG and/or TRACE symbols if you have them defined in the Visual Studio build configuration.

Answer (score 0):

@ Marc Gravell, Divo, Jon: I have try to disassemble the two assemplies with ILDASM. After a deep analysis and compare, I have see that the IL contents is exacly the same, but all the classes and methods, property getter and setter, etc. are in a very different order in the assembly! So if I compare the two assemblies with and hex editor/comparer I see a completely different binary body!

Now I need to understand why VS and Csc interacts with the compiler in this different way!

Do you have a reference to a document that explain the two approches?